# Is SSO impossible using Keycloak OAuth from Direct Grant app to redirected app?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, oauth, single-sign-on, keycloak

Disclaimer: hope this is not against the guidelines here, I also asked this question in the Keycloak forums https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/sso-impossible-from-direct-grant-app-to-redirected-app/319

I have been wrapping my head around this problem and I suspect that it’s not possible, so I'm seeking confirmation or infirmation.

I have 2 apps, which we will call “origin” and “destination”. I need to enable SSO navigation from “origin” to “destination”. Both use the same Keycloak instance (with OAuth, not SAML2).
This would be easy if both apps used redirection... but they don’t, “origin” uses direct grant access.

The end-user logs in to “origin” by providing directly login + password to the app UI, the UI establishes a WebSocket with its backend and uses it to send the user credentials, the backend calls the Keycloak API with login + password and gets tokens for all further operations (API access).
There is one session per WebSocket, the UI never ever knows about tokens or Keycloak but just calls the backend that has the tokens, and when the user logs out the WebSocket is closed and the backend container is destroyed.

“Destination” is more classic, it uses Keycloak normally with redirection.

I want the user to be able to navigate to “destination” without being asked for credentials.

From what I’ve found online, this seems impossible. Refs:

- https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-dev/2016-January/006349.html
- https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/one-client-always-prompts-for-username-and-password-oidc/249/2

So my questions are...

- is it possible?
- could the “origin” app put its tokens in a cookie that would be found by the “destination” app, or more accurately by its Keycloak login UI?
- could the “origin” app call some Keycloak API to inform it that “destination” app can be considered logged in with the same tokens? So that when the “destination” app tries to log in, Keycloak doesn’t even ask for credentials.
- is there any other workaround? In the long term I could ask “origin” to use redirection, but a short term hack would be cool.

I should add that I’m not an authent expert. I have worked with SAML2 in the past so I understand the big picture.

Any help or advice appreciated :-)

Comment: You should not try to "pull up an owl on a globe". Consider using standard flow for authentication in all interactive applications (e.g. applications with UI), and bearer "scheme" for service-to-service communications.

Comment: I don't understand the expression about owls and globes (looked in google, but not hits, except a russian page so maybe it's a russian saying).
If I could easily using standard flows I would be doing it and there would be no question. :-) So basically that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

This works: "origin" gets the JWT from the backend. It sets the JWT on the URL calling "destination", which uses it to say it's logged in. (the JWT is a URL param)

As a consequence both apps are seen as the same from the identity manager (Keycloak). But the user does not have to authenticate when arriving in "destination".

"destination" had to be slightly modified for this.